# Incrementing every value in a parameter pack

Tags: c++, iterator, increment, variadic-functions, parameter-pack

I am currently attempting to increment every value in a parameter pack full of std::vector::iterators of some unknown type. I am currently struggling to get my head around how the `...` syntax works. I would have thought to increment every value it would be `++input_starts ...` but that just gives me a compiler error. Here is the entire function for reference:

```cpp
template<
    typename RETURN,
    typename ... INPUTS
>
void thread_instance(std::function<RETURN(INPUTS ...)> function,
                     typename std::vector<RETURN>::iterator output_start,
                     typename std::vector<RETURN>::iterator output_end,
                     INPUTS ... input_starts)
{
    for (; output_start != output_end; ++output_start, ++input_starts ...)
    {
        *output_start = function(*input_starts ...);
    }
}
```

Comment: The same situation as this question, but with `operator++` instead of `some_function`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011873/c11-variadic-templates-and-comma-separated-expressions-equivalence . (That question's answers also work prior to C++17)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

```
++input_starts ...
```

With this:

```
(++input_starts, ...)
```

That is a C++17 [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) (your use case is analogous to the `push_back_vec()` example on that page).

Simple demo: https://godbolt.org/z/YoY4b1

Comment: thanks for the simple solution!
also, I was wondering if its possible to do somthing similar to that but incremend every iterator by another variable, my code seems to not work as i would expect it to:
```cpp    
threads[i] = std::thread(thread_instance, function, thread_output_start, thread_output_end, (input_vectors.begin() + start_index, ...));
```

Comment: @finlaymorrison: For that I think you need `(input_vectors.begin() + start_index), ...` (you had the ellipsis inside the parentheses, which is wrong).